# Using Python to access web reources. JSON problem?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, authentication, python-requests

I have tried a lot to try to get this to work.

There are CSV resources on a website to that I want to download and save I can do this using firefox but would like to automate the process.

So something like:

```
headers={ 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36'}

payload = { 'email': username, 'password': password}

with requests.Session() as s:
  p=s.post('https://isaacphysics.org/api/v2.10.4/api/auth/segue/authenticate', json=payload,headers=headers)
print(p.status_code)
webpage=s.get('https://isaacphysics.org/api/v2.10.4/api/assignments/assign/group/24684/progress/download' ,headers=headers)
```

The post call returns status 200, returns some user data which verifies it has worked and creates the necessary cookies but the 'get' fails to authenticate.

in firefox the request looks like this:

```
Method: GET
URL: https://isaacphysics.org/api/v2.10.4/api/assignments/assign/group/25090/progress/download
Request Headers:
Host: isaacphysics.org
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: JSESSIONID=9g94t7JUNKJUNK3blif6bkx; isaacCookiesAccepted=1; SEGUE_AUTH_COOKIE="{\"currentUserId\":\"47878\",\"token\":\"0\",\"DATE_EXPIRES\":\"Tue May 12 13:41:48 +0000 2020\",\"HMAC\":\"Tr+eAeSQWU9JUNKJUNKJUNKJUNKJUNKJUNK2MQVrBQ=\"}"
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

and in python
`print(webpage.request.headers)`

gives:

```
{'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36',
 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*',
 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 
'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=1jr9h3wJUNKJUNKJUNKrpfzx; SEGUE_AUTH_COOKIE="{currentUserId:47878,token:0,DATE_EXPIRES:Tue May 12 18:08:00 +0000 2020,HMAC:3LlaQTN/JUNKJUNKJUNKJUNKJUNKJUNKQW4mo=}"; isaacCookiesAccepted=1'}
```

The obvious difference seems to be in SEGUE_AUTH_COOKIE because some of the escape characters have been dropped. I have tried several things and if this is the issue I cannot figure out how to fix it. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the api accept basic auth?

Comment: I have tried this and it doesn't seem to accept it. It took me a long while just to get the post request to work as the more usual data=payload doens't work. Which again makes me think there is something fishy with the JSON Handelling

  However I am not an expert so I might not have exhausted all possibilities.

Comment: You should check the api docs. https://isaacphysics.org/isaac-api/api-docs/ what it says about authentication.

Comment: The link you posted doesn't exist. There is a git hub which I think is potentially useful. https://github.com/isaacphysics/isaac-api/
Unfortunately it is in a pretty poorly documented state. I am not an expert I am a physics teacher with a bit of programming knowledge. I don't think I am going to be able to work it out from the git-hub.

Comment: Let me have a look

Comment: Just to let you know I have managed to get a clunky, inelegant and very buggy work around up and running using selenium. So I do have a way to move on with the project if I never resolve this.

Comment: thats cool. I checked out the github, it seems that it should support oauth authentication as well. but do you know where to get the api keys for it?

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: i couldn't solve it `requests` yet there must be a way. Though i have found a way to do this via `curl` in `bash`. Let me know if i should post it as an answer.

Comment: I'm running on windows.I have never investigated running Bash from within python on a windows machine but it doesn't sound like a good time. Have you narrowed down what the requests issue is at all? What is the difference between the Bash solution and using requests? 
That said I would support any answer over no answer it could be useful to someone else in the future who knows. On that line I should maybe post details of my selenium solution at some point too.

Comment: and THANK YOU for all your effort.

Comment: @user3604932 Hi, I work on Isaac Physics, thanks for your interest :) It may be possible that what you're trying to do is in violation of our ToS (https://isaacphysics.org/terms) but we are actually more interested in knowing what you wanted to do and whether we can help. Feel free to contact us here (https://isaacphysics.org/contact) and let us know!